# How do I name the rows as A,B,C,D,E in this dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100,(5, 4)), columns=list('WXYZ'))
print(df)
```

I want to rename the row/index name to A,B,C,D,E instead of 0,1,2,3,4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `index=` parameter when creating your DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100,(5, 4)), columns=list('WXYZ'), index=list('ABCDE'))
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    W   X   Y   Z
A  84  96  55  28
B  51  50  11  87
C  15  95   9   6
D  28   1  69  10
E  55  61  97  74
```

---

EDIT: To drop `W` column:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100,(5, 4)), columns=list('WXYZ'), index=list('ABCDE'))

df = df.drop('W', axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    X   Y   Z
A  76  59  96
B  87  30  51
C  13   8  48
D   9  60  70
E  78  94  95
```

Comment: Hii, what do i do if i want to remove the column W?

Comment: @GROOT You can use `df = df.drop('W', axis=1)`

Comment: it gives me an error

KeyError: "['W'] not found in axis"

Comment: @GROOT It means you don't have `[W]` column in your dataframe. See my edit how to use `.drop` method.